# Deserialization and object references

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, deserialization

I've got an `ObservableCollection<Recipe>` saved as a *JSON* string in my *IsolatedStorageSettings*.

The class `Recipe` has a field called `Category` that is initialized by this code:

```
[JsonProperty]
private Category _category = RecipesViewModel.BaseCategories.First();
```

A `Category` is something like this:

```
[JsonProperty]
public Categories BaseCategory;

/// <summary>
///     Background picture for the cagtegory
/// </summary>
public string Picture
{
    get { return string.Format(@"/Assets/CategoriesPictures/{0}.jpg", BaseCategory); }
}
/// <summary>
///     Category's name
/// </summary>
public string Name
{
    get { return BaseCategory.ToString(); }
}

/// <summary>
///     List of recipes that belong to this category
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<Recipe> Recipes
{
    get { return App.ViewModel.GetRecipesByCategory(this); }
}

/// <summary>
/// We need this to let everyone know that something may have been changed in our collections
/// </summary>
public void UpdateCategory()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Recipes);
}
```

where `BaseCategory` is a simple *enum*

```
public enum Categories
{
    Breakfast,
    Lunch,
    Appetizer,
    Sidedish,
    Soup,
    Dessert,
    Beverages
}
```

At the moment I've just one `Recipe` in my `ObservableCollection<Recipe>`, and this is the *JSON* that's saved in the *IsolatedStorageSettings*:

```
[
  {
    "_addedDate": "2013-11-10T19:08:00.8968706+01:00",
    "_category": {
      "BaseCategory": 2
    },
    "_ingredients": [],
    "_recipeName": "recipeName",
    "_steps": [],
    "_temperature": 0.0
  }
]
```

The `BaseCategories` is declared as

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<Category> BaseCategories { get; private set; }
```

and it's build by this method:

```
private static void BuildCategories()
{
    var categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
    foreach (var enumValue in from category in typeof(Categories).GetFields()
                              where category.IsLiteral
                              select (Categories)category.GetValue(typeof(Categories)))
    {
        categories.Add(new Category { BaseCategory = enumValue });
    }
    BaseCategories = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Category>(categories);
}
```

What happens is that, during my data loading method, the first element of `BaseCategories` becomes the `Category` that is written in the *JSON*.

In this case it turns from *Breakfast* to *Appetizer* (which is the `Category` of the only saved `Recipe`).

This is the code that I use to load my data:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    if (BaseCategories.IsEmpty())
        BuildCategories();
    // Load data from IsolatedStorage
    var jsonString = "";
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(RecipesKey, out jsonString))
    {
        // BEFORE THIS LINE EVERYTHING IS FINE
        Recipes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Recipe>>(jsonString);
        // AFTER THIS LINE, THE FIRST CATEGORY IN BaseCategories IS CHANGED
    }
    UpdateCategories();
    IsDataLoaded = true;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on there?

I've been working on this code all day long so my head is gone for now!

Answer (score 0):

Seems very familar to the ASP.NET. About the method. Did you noticed that "jsonString" variable is empty ? You're trying to get something from serializable json object, whereas "something" is empty. And try to use explicit type convertion to type of the Recipce.

Comment: The `jsonString` var is empty because it's passed as an `out` parameter to this line `if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(RecipesKey, out jsonString))`, which loads it from the `IsolatedStorage`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd suggest using proper annotation attributes in your view model using: [DataContract] on the whole object, [DataMember] on properties, that should be serialized and [IgnoreDataMember] on properties, that should be ignored by JSON.net.
Also the class Category should use standard properties, that are initialised with proper values in specific method, instead of using hardcoded getters:

```
public Categories BaseCategory { get; set; }
public string Picture { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
```

In your Recipe the use serialized BaseCategory and IgnoreDataMember Category:

```
[DataMember]
public Categories BaseCatagory { get; set; }
[IgnoreDataMember]
public Category Category { get; set; }
```

Let me know, if it helps in any way.

Comment: I'm using `JsonProperty` attribute because I've marked my classes with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` to avoid adding `[IgnoreDataMember]` on each field. I'll try using properties as they should be used, but I'm not sure that this is why I've got this weird problem

Comment: I just tried with your suggestions but the problem persists. When the string is deserialized, the first `Category` of the `BaseCategories` collection becomes the one that's in the deserialized `Recipe` and this is quite odd :\

Comment: Can you please provide simple VS project where we can reproduce the error, with only the necessary classes? Thanks.